# Efficiently solving coding puzzle with long array?

Tags: arrays

I have been having some difficulty thinking of an efficient way of solving this problem and making it work for long arrays. I am pretty sure that I don't know a programming technique needed to solve it. I would be thankful if you could help me!

The problem:Jack is a little businessman. He found out a way to earn money by buying electricity on days when it's cheap and selling it when it's much more expensive. He stores the electricity in a battery he made by himself. You are given N, the number of days Jack knows the cost of electricity for, and X, the amount of money Jack has available to invest in electricity, and in the next line you are given N days with the value(buy/sell value) of the electricity. Your job is to determine when Jack should buy and when he should sell electricity in order to earn as much money as possible and simply print the largest possible sum of money he can earn. The value of the electricity is always an integer but depending on the amount of money Jack has, the amount of electricity and money he has may be floating point numbers. I have a few ideas of how to solve the problem, but they're all very inefficient when it comes to long arrays.

```
Example: 
Input: 
4 10
4 10 5 20
Output:100, because he buys electricity on the 1st day and the sells it on the 2nd and buys it on the 3rd and sells it on the 4th day.

Example num. 2: 
Input: 
3 21
10 8 3
Output:21, because it's better if he doesn't buy/sell any electricity.


Example num. 3: 
Input:
3 10
8 10 14
Output:17.5, because he buys electricity on the 1st day, but he sells it on the 3rd day.
```

Answer (score 0):

On any day, Jack has either cash or electricity.

On any day other than the last, he buys electricity if he has cash, and the price on the next day is higher.

On any day, he sells electricity if he has electricity, and it is either the last day, or the price on the next day is lower.